# What is this ' : MAXKEY(), root() ' , used in class of c++?

Tags: c++, class

I'm studying Data Structure in c++, 2-3 Tree.

And I wnat to know about the ' : MAXKEY(), root()'.

```
class Two3 {
public:
    Two3(KeyType max, Two3Node<KeyType>* init = 0)
        : MAXKEY(max), root(init) {}; //constructor
    Boolean function(…);
private:
    Two3Node<KeyType>* root;
    KeyType MAXKEY;
```

Here's that I want to know.

> : MAXKEY(max), root(init) {}; //constructor

Comment: This should be covered in whatever C++ book you're learning from - this is just the normal way for constructors to initialise member variables.

Comment: I don't know how to search about this. Please tell me what's the best key for searching this problem... I could not find this when key is, "what is the " : " ???, like this..

Comment: If you don't already have [a good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) then you should consider getting one - you can't learn a language form guesswork and Google searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an initialization list. It says "initialize `MAXKEY` with `max` and initialize `root` with `init`". Initializers run before control is passed into constructor body.

Comment: I is actually an *member initialization list*.  an *initialization list* is a bracketed list